# Intellij docker with live update of EAR inside websphere

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose, websphere-liberty

I have a docker container with Websphere libery profile running inside. In general when ever i change code i build my application and deploy manually into websphere. However this is very tedious.

Is there any way i could deploy changes dynamically into websphere inside Docker container everytime i do changes in the code? I want this to work as a local server configured directly inside Intellij.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this might have been to create a remote WebSphere Liberty server but on trying this it looks like Intellij does not support remote deployment for WebSphere Liberty.  Have you thought about using WebSphere Developer Tools which fully support Liberty in a Docker container (see https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/developing-applications-using-wdt-liberty-docker/)?  One other way that involves a bit of setup would be to add volumes in your docker container - one that maps from /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer to a local copy of the server configuration (so you can modify the server configuration locally), and one that maps from a new path to the root of where your application projects are located on your machine.  You could then create a loose configuration xml file in the apps directory of the server configuration for each application.  More information about loose configuration files is here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_loose_applications.html.